# VB.NET Error Expression doesn't produce a value

Tags: vb.net

I am developin' a facebook app using facebook c# sdk
I converted the following code to vb.net:

```
var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
 {
      ContentType = "image/jpeg",
      FileName = Path.GetFileName(_filename)
  }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(_filename));
```

The converted code:

```
  Dim mediaObject = New FacebookMediaObject() With { _
  .ContentType = "image/jpeg", _
 .FileName = Path.GetFileName(_filename) _
}.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(_filename))
```

but it gives me the following error:
`Expression doesn't produce a value.`
Can anyone suggest a solution please?

Comment: Hmm, that's valid syntax.  You must mention your VS version.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Comment: @HansPassant is it?  Can you call methods on an object initializer like that in VB?  Trying it now with some boilerplate types and it seems not (VS2010).

Comment: It is fine in VS2013.  2010 is already 4 years ago, can't remember.  They've done a lot of work on VB.NET in the last versions to make converting from/to C# easier.

Comment: @HansPassant Good to know.  Must be an undocumented change - `New` seems to have always been an rvalue keyword only in VB. I didn't think there were any changes to VB in 2013 and nothing is mentioned about the change to `New` semantics in the 2012 documentation. Must be buried in the language reference somewhere...

Comment: @HansPassant ...nevermind, I'm completely wrong.  It works with `Dim v = New O() With {}.M`.  It doesn't work with `Dim v As New O() With {}.M`.  Learn something every day!

Comment: If you separate out the `mediaObject.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(_filename))` step, does it still complain? Does it look as if VB is not recognizing that `SetValue` is a function?

Answer (score 0):

In VS2008, it will work as

```
Dim mediaObject = New FacebookMediaObject With { _
                      .ContentType = "image/jpeg", _
                      .FileName = Path.GetFileName(_filename) _
                      }
mediaObject.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(_filename))
```

Or perhaps you intended SetValue to be a function (!):

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Public Class FacebookMediaObject
        'TODO: make these properties
        Public ContentType As String
        Public FileName As String
        Public Contents As Byte()

        Public Function SetValue(ByVal b() As Byte) As FacebookMediaObject
            Contents = b
            Return Me
        End Function

    End Class

    Sub Main()

        Dim _filename As String = "whatever"

        Dim mediaObject = (New FacebookMediaObject With { _
                           .ContentType = "image/jpeg", _
                           .FileName = Path.GetFileName(_filename) _
                           }).SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(_filename))

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Is `SetValue()` a function in the C# version?

Comment: Yes.  Which makes your code incorrect, the variable stores the return value of SetValue(), not of the *new* operator.

Comment: @HansPassant Assuming you are referring to the second portion of code, `SetValue()` returns `Me`. I know, it's horrible, but it does work make the OP's converted code compile.

Comment: No, I meant the 1st snippet.  SetValue() is a method of FacebookMediaObject.  Part of the api, you cannot just replace it like you did in your 2nd snippet.

Comment: It does look to be defined the same way in the API : `public FacebookMediaObject SetValue(byte[] value) { _value = value; return this;}`(not that this changes the fact that it can't simply be arbitrarily replaced - just that it does end up returning the new object via `.SetValue()`